# Slow frame rate for gstreamer stream

Tags: performance, video-streaming, gstreamer, frame-rate

I am using the following command for a gstreamer pipeline for a videostream from a webcam:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videorate ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=25/1 ! xvimagesink
```

Unfortunately the displayed **stream has a very low framerate**, it feels like maybe 3 frames per second.
I don't really know what could be the problem here. How can I increase the performance for this video stream?

I already tried reducing the width and height values to lower the resolution but this did not leave me with any noticable improvement.
Might the thing with the format be slowing me down? Maybe it is helful to know that I chose the I420 as they where needed for a nodewebRTC implementation where a function was seemingl only called with frames of this format.

Answer (score 0):

Check you camera capabilities first, e.g. with `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext -d /dev/video0`. Might be that `I420` requires conversion. If your PC is not able to keep-up with the conversion, you'll see a message like:

`WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.`

If so, consider using `MJPG` to stream at higher framerate.